# Can background images be used with google asset studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some background images that have been designed using Photoshop. I did the same image using Illustrator that uses vector graphics, but when deployed the image did not scale very well. Sometimes too big or small. From experimenting, the photoshop images looked much better, even though it used raster images.

I have set the layout background property to this:

```
android:background="@drawable/camera"
```

I have just a few questions:

1. What is better for creating background images, photoshop (raster) or Illustrator (vector)?
2. As all smart devices are different dpi's and sizes. Is what recommended size should I create the original image when designing it in photoshop or Illustrator?
3. I noticed that asset studio can create scalable images but can the icon launcher be used for background images, or is it only for launcher icons?

> Android Studio 0.5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This depends on what your final image should look like or which
   tool is better suited for your needs. PS is more suitable to create
   pixel graphics and IL is better used for shapes, buttons and so on. In the
   end it doesn't matter for android, because internally graphics are
   interpreted as bitmaps and therefore are pixel-based. Android
   unfortunately doesn't support SVG by default, although there are libs
   available.
2. You should have a look at the supported screens range
   http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range
   You can't really create background images that fit every screen but at least you can approximate them, so only some parts of the image are cut off eventually. Alternatively you can use 9drawables to stretch an image to fit every screen. In that case you will need an image with stretching marks as described here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDrawables/article.html#drawables_9patch
3. Asses Studio is best used for Icons. However you could use it for generating the above mentioned 9drawables in the correct sizes: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html